# Call to undefined method ActiveRecord\Config::initialise() composer

Tags: php, class, activerecord, composer-php

Hey everyone I'm following a tutorial on Composer, I've installed ActiveRecord and I'm trying to create a database model. Whenever I load the page though I get this error: Call to undefined method ActiveRecord\Config::initialise()

Here's my setup file in index.php

```
require_once "vendor/php-activerecord/php-activerecord/ActiveRecord.php";

ActiveRecord\Config::initialise(function($cfg) {

    //setting up a model (which is the representation of a table) 
    $cfg->set_model_directory('models');
    $cfg->set_connections(array(
        'development' => 'mysql://root:tutsplus@localhost/blog'
    ));
});

$posts = Post::all();   
print_r($posts);
```

?>

And here's where I declare Post

```
class Post extends ActiveRecord\Model{}
```

I really cannot find the reason this isn't working, I actually did this instead to see if manually creating a new Post instance would fix the initialisation problem but it didn't, it had exactly the same error:

```
$post_class = new Post;
$posts = $post_class->all();    
print_r($posts);
```

I'm really stumped on this one, I've usually managed to find something that fixes my problem on here but this is just nope. There is literally no difference to the tutorial code that I can see and I've checked it loads of times. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(edit: the duplicate php-activerecord folders at the top isn't a code problem, the folder is actually duplicated and I haven't got round to moving the contents yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point one: When using Composer, you are supposed to only include "vendor/autoload.php", and nothing else. Composer does the rest of autoloading for you.

Point two: It is called `initialize` with a Z, not S. You might simply have misspelled that method name.